# Constructing an adapted process for a given stopping time

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, filtrations

Given a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and a stopping time $T$, show that there exists an adapted process  $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that $$T=\inf \{n \geq 0 : X_n >0\}$$

I'm really lost where to even begin here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try a little reverse engineering: If you had such a process $X=(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ (with $X_n\ge 0$, for each $n$, to keep it simple), could you represent $\{T=n\}$ in terms of the $X_n$s? Now what's the simplest choice of adapted process $X=(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ consistent with that representation?

Comment: @JohnDawkins would something like $X_n=\mathbf 1_{\{T=n\}}$ work?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work.